# open Microsoft Outlook from web browser

Tags: javascript, outlook

is it possible to open outlook on a client's local machine or outlook 365 to the new meeting request page from the browser.

I would like to pass in the send to email list, but leave all other fields unfilled so the client can enter those data.

I have been looking at Outlook  REST APIs, but it seems to be actually sending the mail rather than just opening the page. 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook/rest/javascript-tutorial

Comment: As far as I know you can only open the users default email client. If that happens to be Outlook then itll open outlook.

Comment: You cannot invoke a specific application. You can only invoke the system's default email handler, which may or may not be Outlook, to send a new email.

Comment: yea I didn't think you can open outlook new meeting page from the browser. What about outlook 365, have any suggestion on that?